# Can someone explain what each pin does on an LM3914 dot/bar graph chip?

Tags: pins, integrated-circuit

I got an LM3914 chip to control a ten segment bar graph, but I am confused on how to wire it. The date sheet is not helping me with what pins do what and how to wire it.

I need to know how it works and please don't be hyper technical I am still new to electronics.

Comment: the 2nd page of the datasheet has a really straightforward example.

Comment: But it does not explain what each pin does.

Comment: Well, it's just not in a nice tabular format a lot of datasheets has. You've got to hunt for it. Alternatively, you can search for lm3914+{pin #/pin name}.

Comment: The LM391x is a fancy resistor divider and comparator array, with some expansion and control.

Comment: This would be easier to answer with a link to the data sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I think the picture on page 8 of the data sheet, and the text starting from page 9, explains it about as clearly as anyone can make it. I hope you didn't stop reading it after seeing those cryptic graphs?

In short: there's not much more to it than a pin to set the LED brightness, a pin to select between dot and bar mode, a pin for the input voltage to be measured, and the pins for the LEDs and the power supply.